# Issue creating a Homebrew cask (livecheck unable to find the latest version)

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I'm trying to submit a cask for [Tentacle Sync Studio](https://tentaclesync.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003866805-Tentacle-Sync-Studio-macOS-) but I'm having issues with livecheck being able to find the most recent version. I ran `brew audit --new-cask tentacle-sync-studio` and received the following error `- Version '1.30' differs from '' retrieved by livecheck.`

```
cask "tentacle-sync-studio" do
  version "1.30"
  sha256 "4f7bdaef85b78f576babac91d57da3b3276cc98a2f81ac621bea96a48fe8796a"

  url "https://tentaclesync.com/files/downloads/ttsyncstudio-v#{version.dots_to_underscores}.dmg"
  name "Tentacle Sync Studio"
  desc "Automatically synchronize video and audio via timecode"
  homepage "https://tentaclesync.com/"
  
  livecheck do
    url "https://tentaclesync.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003866805-Tentacle-Sync-Studio-macOS-"
    strategy :page_match
    regex(%r{/v?(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)/ttsyncstudio\.dmg}i)
  end

  depends_on macos: ">= :high_sierra"

  app "Tentacle Sync Studio.app"
end
```

I might not be using the correct "strategy" and I honestly have no idea how to set the regex despite reading Homebrew's instructions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vitalsource-bookshelf` cask [had a similar issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/112522):

> Previous livecheck URL had Cloudflare protection, use API URL instead.

You'll want to change

```
https://tentaclesync.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003866805-Tentacle-Sync-Studio-macOS-
```

to

```
https://tentaclesync.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/en-us/articles/115003866805
```

However, a few more changes must be made for the livecheck to work:

1. Change the regex to `href=.*?/ttsyncstudio-v?(\d+(?:[._-]\d+)+)\.dmg`

   - We want to match this string: `href=\"https://tentaclesync.com/files/downloads/ttsyncstudio-v1_30.dmg`
   - `href=.*?` is a convention in `homebrew/cask`
   - `[._-]` matches a dot, underscore, or hyphen (another convention)
2. Add a `do` to `strategy :page_match` to change underscores to dots:

   ```rb
   strategy :page_match do |page, regex|
     page.scan(regex).map { |match| match[0].tr("_", ".") }
   end
   ```

   `match[0]` corresponds to the regex capture `(\d+(?:[._-]\d+)+)`

Finally, your cask file should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/FnControlOption/1258cabe4d9b2d8c0d51d9637afa11b0).

Comment: I just ran `brew audit` and it passed! Thanks so much, and I appreciate the explanation of the Ruby regex string <3